# how to pass pearmeter during the uploading of image to the webserver in android

Tags: android

I am working on the uploading of Photo on the  php web service, i was successful in uploading the file without parameter.

Now i want to pass two other parameter that is "search_id" and "user_id".

i got some hint from http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/03/09/android/android-upload-image-to-server/ link but not able to save the file at server side.

please help me,

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [Image Upload with additional Data](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/android-upload-image-or-file-using-http-post-multi-part/). It let you to upload image with some additional data such as Caption etc.

Comment: Thanks yar Venky, i thing it is a perfect method to upload image with parameter.